# Unix command tr -c usage

Tags: unix, tr

I am having trouble understanding the -c option in tr (Unix command).

Looking at this format for `tr`: `tr [Options] set1 [set2]`

I understand that `-c` is an [option] available for `tr` which means that "it takes the complement of set1 ( aka, all characters not in set1). But, can someone please give an example of how to use this command and explain the benefits.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means to complement the character range. When you complement the string `A-Z` you get *Any character that is not in A ... Z*.

Sometimes it is much easier to specify a task with the complement. Suppose you want to count the number of semicolons in a C source file. You delete all non-semicolons and count what's left:

```
tr -d -c \; < file.c | wc -c
```

Comment: This answer should be added to POSIX standard